# Wordpress Menu Drop-downs hidden behind div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created a form for a Wordpress site http://www.bassetandbeagle.org/adoptionapplication/ and in the CSS code I put div position: absolute, so that the form would scale on mobile devices.

```
#formContainer {
min-width: 950px;
max-width: 950px;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1; }
```

Now the drop-down menus, above the form, are hidden behind it.

I attempted to set a higher z-index for the menu:

```
.nav-menu{
position: relative;
z-index: 1; }
```

But this had no apparent effect.  I tried 1, 100, 1000... nada

I was able to get the drop-downs to show up again, by changing the .nav-menu to position: absolute.  Unfortunately, this screwed up the positioning of the menus on the page.

I am pretty sure I am on the right track with the z-index property, based upon the other posts I have read.  So, what am I doing wrong here?

Thx

Comment: As you wrote, there is something about the position absolute, because if you remove it, the navigation gets on top. I tried to change some Z-index but still cant figure out how. Will look some more on it :)

Comment: @shawrich please have a look on my answer and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution of your problem -

**CSS:**

**style.css line: 1431**

```
.site {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 68.5714rem;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/  /* remove this css rule and you will see the dropdown menu*/
}
```

**Note:** Check you site that where your `.site` class is applying and make the changes in css as per need.

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

Comment: Just to make my life easier when theme updates come along, I added .site { overflow: visible; } to my child theme css file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: absolute` from `#formContainer`.